# Integral returns function of variable that was integrated over

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8 and fixed in 10**

---

When I enter

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[(y1)^2 + (y2)^2 + (y3)^2]*1/(1 + (y3)^2)
* Exp[-2*((y1)^2 + (y2)^2)/(1 + (y3)^2)], {y1, -∞, ∞}, {y2, -∞, ∞}, {y3, -10, 10}]
```

into Mathematica, I get the result

```
ConditionalExpression[(
 E^((2 y3^2)/(1 + y3^2)) \[Pi]^(3/2) Sqrt[y3^2] (-1 + Sqrt[1/y3^2] y3 
 + Erfc[(Sqrt[2] y3)/Sqrt[1 + y3^2]]))/(Sqrt[2] y3 Sqrt[1 + y3^2]), Re[y3^2] > 0]
```

However, this is a  function of y3, which can't possibly be right. Apparently when other people execute this, they get a different and more sensible result. Does anybody know what setting in Mathematica might be causing this? If it helps, I am using Mathematica 9 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I got 10.2436, is that what you are look for?

Comment: It appears to return the integral over `y1` and `y2` having skipped the integral over `y3`.  It also appears the integral over `y3` cannot be done symbolically by *Mathematica*, but that is not a reason for the result to be wrong.  Seems like a bug to me.  This has been fixed in V10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was fixed in version 10.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking at the final result then this could help.

```
  int = Integrate[
       1/Sqrt[(y1)^2 + (y2)^2 + (y3)^2]*1/(1 + (y3)^2)*
        Exp[-2*((y1)^2 + (y2)^2)/(1 + (y3)^2)], {y1, -Infinity, 
        Infinity}, {y2, -Infinity, Infinity}];
        NIntegrate[int, {y3, -10, 10}]

(*10.2436*)
```